# Store a long double in several double variables

Tags: c++, json, casting

I have to store a `long double` variable in JSON format. JSON supports `double` variables but not `long double`. Then I have to split the `long double` value in several `double` values, but I don't know how to do that easily.

I already did that for `long long int` variables by this way :

```
std::vector<long int> long_long_int__to__long_int(long long int x)
{
  std::vector<long int> split;
  const unsigned long int n = sizeof(long long int) / sizeof(long int);
  for(unsigned long int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
  {
    split.push_back((long int)(x % (long long int)std::numeric_limits<long int>::max));
    x /= (long long int)std::numeric_limits<long int>::max;
  }
  split.push_back(x);
  return split;
}
```

**Any idea how to do that with floating points variables ?**

Comment: if that's convenient for you, you could just store all individual bytes - or strings (sure, they aren't correctly types in your json that way, but having ints/floats that don't really represented numbers in your data sounds worse to me - without knowing your exact use-use). also very easy to transform

Comment: @b.buchhold : Of course, but very costly in term of final json size. It's designed to store a lot of data in a json format (similar use of dumping in a binary file).

Comment: Guys, be gentle, explain me why downvote this question ?

Comment: let's say you write each byte as hex value. this way, you write 2 chars per byte and thus 16 chars for a 64bit value. That is much shorter than your solution for ints and transfers to float.

Comment: You're right, in hex it could be a good solution !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I can think of, and it's applicable to your long long int problem as well.

1. consider any type you want to store as a array of hex values, whether it's a long long int or long double.
2. choose one [Binary-to-text encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding) algorithm and use it to convert the array to a readable string.
3. store the string to JSON

Answer (score 1):

Store two doubles: `(double)x` and `(double)(x - (double)x)`.  (And pay attention to compilers bugs and switches affecting the handling of precision, they may cause issues when using such techniques, [a gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=323) for instance).